# Can force gstreamer to request audio (opencv client)

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

I'm connecting to an RTSP server with:

```
        pipe = f"rtspsrc protocols=tcp ..."
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(pipe, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

(OpenCV was compiled with gstreamer support).

Looking at the RTSP setup traffic over wireshark, I see that only the video RTP stream (not audio) is being requested.

OpenCV obviously can't receive the audio, but is it possible to get gstreamer to request the audio and then discard it. (I'm trying to debug a connection issue that only occurs when audio is requested and would like to use this code to reproduce it).

Comment: request audio from a standalone gstreamer pipeline. you don't need opencv, right? so don't involve it. also gives this question a bit more focus.

Comment: "OpenCV obviously can't receive the audio," -- no, it wont. it's a computer-vision library.

Comment: I don't want it to. I just want gstreamer to receive it and toss it out. The RTSP negotiation shows that it doesn't request it.

Comment: I'm trying to write that test frames and frame rates are correct for a video source that has video-only issues (stalled stream) when only when audio is being requested.